Schematic of proportional valve driver
I am not the most competent person in electronics, so I am faced with a question. in my project I need to control a proportional valve asco202. NXPERIA in its article gives the following scheme:

The duty cycle for this scheme is divided into the following phases:

Both MOSFETs are open to move the piston to the working position faster.
During the hold phase, the lower arm transistor is open and the upper MOSFET is controlled by PWM. Inductive emission is damped through the lower diode.
Both transistors are closed for faster return to the initial position

The first question I have is which diodes are better to use for this circuit, rectifier diodes or Schottky diodes?
Next, I came across the following (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275406458_Analysis_of_Dither_in_PWM_Control_on_Electro-hydraulic_Proportional_Valve), the author of which cites this scheme:

Can you explain the advantages of this scheme, because, as I understand, such an inductor current ripple will increase and the PWM squelch range will decrease? Or such an inclusion simplifies the algorithm of superimposing the dithering signal? And is it possible to add capacitors for energy recovery in reverse as in the figure above?
